# Strange error message from javascript "undefined some constant string"

Tags: javascript

In the code below variable dogName is declared before being called, however no value is assigned to it. That means I expect JavaScript considering it as null.

```
function myDog() {
    var dogName;
    console.log(dogName + 'says woof');
    dogName = 'fido';
}
myDog();
```

but to my shock the error message is

```
undefined says woof
```

Why? I thought the error message had to be "null value!" or no error message at all and it could simply display "null says woof".

Why "undefined says woof" is thrown instead?

Edit: it implied to me that the "says woof" is undefined!

Comment: You didn't assign `dogName` until after the `console.log()`. Until then it's `undefined`.

Comment: Oh! got it. you mean javascript has replaced the dogName with "undefined!"

Comment: `says woof` isn't an error message, it's in your `console.log()` call.

Comment: @Barmar oh! you are right! good point

Comment: From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript: "JavaScript distinguishes between `null`, which is a value that indicates a deliberate non-value (and is only accessible through the null keyword), and `undefined`, which is a value of type 'undefined' that indicates an uninitialized value — that is, a value hasn't even been assigned yet...in JavaScript **it is possible to declare a variable without assigning a value to it. If you do this, the variable's type is `undefined`**."

Comment: @torazaburo i wonder why you didn't provide it as a separate answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the variable to be initialized to `null`, it should be:

```
var dogName = null;
```

Otherwise, the default value of new variables is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript:

> JavaScript distinguishes between null, which is a value that indicates a deliberate non-value (and is only accessible through the null keyword), and `undefined`, which is a value of type 'undefined' that indicates an uninitialized value — that is, a value hasn't even been assigned yet...in JavaScript **it is possible to declare a variable without assigning a value to it. If you do this, the variable's type is `undefined`**."